# Android Studio - how can I learn what a particular interface element is in a project?

Tags: android, xcode, android-studio, storyboard

I'm working with Android Studio and am trying to understand if there's a way to quickly identify a particular interface element's class that I'm seeing on the screen. In my previous work with xCode:

- I could go to a storyboard,
- find an appropriate view controller
- Select the interface element
- open identity inspector to find the class name.

[image]

**Is there a way to quickly identify interface element's class in Android Studio?**

For example, I'm looking at the GitHub open source project and see that it has about a hundred files in its layout folder and a lot of them are very small and fragmented. How would I find what class is responsible for presenting the controllers like "Mine", "Starred" and "All" in the screenshot below?

[image]

Here's what I see in xCode storyboard or interface builder file:

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean, look at the xml and you see what class it is

Comment: That particular project has close to 100 xml files, many of which are named very similarly. Is there a way to find out this info more efficiently than just scanning filenames and guessing which one has the interface on screen?

Comment: If you mean which activity presents the view no there is nothing that tells you this because views are referenced by their id's which is a number. They can be inflated in many places and not just a single class